# What are the criteria of becoming a target for turrets in Prey (2017)?

Tags: prey

I know that if you purchase too many Typhon abilities, you will be counted as alien by various Talos-1 systems like the turrets. And there is icon indicating how much you are transformed towards that.

I've purchased 2 abilities at a cost of 3 and 2 neuromods each. This caused the icon to fill to half. I concluded that I will be counted as an alien after purchasing either 2 more abilities or spending 4 more neuromods on typhon abilities. Yet after purchasing a single 2 neuromod cost ability I am getting a full icon.

I've also purchased few abilities from "Scientist" branch, for increased Psi capacity and for additional chips for Psychoscope, but I doubt those are counted as typhon abilities.

So, how is this actually counted? Or is the indicator not really indicating the exact process of transformation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to users in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/prey/comments/69t992/how_many_alien_nueromods_does_in_take_for_turrets/), the general consensus is that it takes **3** Typhon skill activations to be considered alien enough to be targeted by turrets.

> Third one will designate you as a target.
>
> for me it was three.
>
> Nah, I did three separate skills and they started attacking after the third for me as well.
>
> For me it took 3 but some turrets attack me and some don't
>
> 3 but honestly turrets most of the time when you enter an area will be dead or you can just emp them then hack them.

Answer (score 1):

On which difficulty are you playing on? On hard, even the first typhon ability (mimicry1) filled that bar 50%. 
I think it's either the number of typhon skills or the number of invested neuromods into typhon trees which determ the grade of typhonisation. Probably also the difficulty setting plays a role.
Besides that, i have no clue or further information.

Comment: I'm playing on Nightmare difficulty, got Mind Control and Psy-shock skills to get 50% indicator. Have no idea, why Mimicry 1 made 50% for you, as it is only 1 skill, which costs 2 neuromods (while I've got 2 skills with 5 neuromods total). Possibly, icon have only 2 states - half filled and fully filled.

Comment: @lentinant, I can confirm that the icon was 50% filled with 2 Typhon mods, which led me to (incorrectly) believe I could safely purchase a third one. The icon most likely only shows 2 states.